# Python Code to automate process so that text file contains last 30 days of data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to automate a process where I import data to a txt file. At present I have to manually amend this code

```py
WHERE date_utc >= '2019-12-26'
```

I would like to be able to read the text file `Tracker.txt` and get the last `date_utc` value. and add a day to that date , so if it was 2019-12-26 then it would be 2019-12-27.
I would also like to be able to delete all dates in the text file that are older than 30 days.

The aim is to ensure that text file is updated by writing only the latest data to the current data , and remove the old data so the file is always containing the latest 30 days of data.
At present I am having to manually delete the old rows of data and then manually add the date and then run this python code

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
from configuration import parameters
import sys

tu_path = os.path.join('postgresql+psycopg2://' + parameters.TU_USER + ':' + parameters.TU_PWD +
                           '@' + parameters.TU_HOST + ':' + parameters.TU_PORT + '/' +
                           parameters.TU_DB)
tu_db = create_engine(tu_path)
query = '''SELECT
           date_utc,
           designator,
           departure_utc,
           arrival_utc,
           block_minutes,
           operator_name,
           operator_country,
           operator_class,
           departure_city_name,
           departure_country_name,
           departure_region_name
           FROM tracked_data.master_vw
           WHERE date_utc >= '2019-12-26' '''

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, tu_db)
df.to_csv(r'Tracker.txt',header=True, index=False,sep='\t', mode='a')
```

Comment: Why not extract the date string to its own variable? Also, Postgres has date math functions, I assume. You can select a 30 day range from it, and don't use `mode=a` to append to your file

Comment: Can you not just make the query retrieve the last 30 days and completely overwrite the txt file? Does the DB have an index on the `date_utc` column?

Comment: the text file is 3gb in size. so to import the latest 30 days of data through sql takes about 1 hour to run. so I only wanted to add the latest data if possible

Comment: What if there is no file to begin with? Then you manually enter the date 30 days ago?

Comment: if I manually add the date 30 days ago , to a new text file it takes 3 hours to import the data , due to the size of database. This is why I was trying to find a solution automate the process by reading the date in column 1 of the tab delimited text file.

Comment: @BrettD but that's not how files work... you remove/replace data - you have to effectively replace the whole file anyway

Comment: Seems that ideally you should (if the file system is accessible or can made be for the server) - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html

Comment: However, the basic thing looks like you could adjust the query to `SELECT... FROM tracked_data.master_vw WHERE (NOW() - date_utc) <= INTERVAL '30 days'` and probably best to make sure you've got an index on the `date_utc` column

Comment: Thanks I will have a look , I was able to extract the last date by using this code

Comment: with open('Tracker.txt', 'r') as f:
     opened_file = f.readlines()
     var = opened_file[-1].split('\t')[0]
     print (var)